# How to set up GUI date input to retain format look and feel

Tags: swing, user-interface, spinner, simpledateformat, jformattedtextfield

Okay I've tried this a few different ways and haven't been able to get it to do what I want it to. I've also visited this page: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.text/formtext_FormTextDate.html

I have a spinner:

```
SimpleDateFormat datePattern = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
JLabel endLabel = new JLabel("End Date: ");
        JSpinner endSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());         
        endSpinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(endSpinner, datePattern.toPattern()));
```

This automatically loads today's date. I would prefer it to just show MM/DD/YYYY within the actual gui. This would give it the look of being date input without requiring a specific date to be entered if not required. Then as soon as you start spinning it would take a date. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Any suggestions? I've also started looking up FormattedTextFields as well as an option. Would this be a better route to go?

If so, how can I set up the FormattedTextField to look like this: [  /  /    ]. Then when you put input in, keep that format, requiring only digits and 2 digits for month, 2 digits for day, and 4 digits for year. I would assume I'd have to set up some sort of pattern instead of initializing the FormattedTextField as a date? For example:

```
JFormattedTextField date = new JFormattedTextField(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"));
date.setValue("  /  /    ");
```

But all you would have to do is clear out the field and it would no longer look like a date. I want it to at least keep the '/' no matter what you do.

Sorry for the long drawn out question.

Comment: Realized that date.setValue("  /  /    "); Doesn't actually work. I tried this and whenever I click out of the text box it clears the input. It also appears as an empty box in the GUI:
    JFormattedTextField endTextField = new JFormattedTextField(new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy"));
   endTextField.setColumns(10);

Comment: It appears this may work for me:
   JFormattedTextField type30ELBeginTextField = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("##'/##'/####"));